# Creating function arrays

Tags: javascript

please can you help me fix my code. In my quiz I have got 2 buttons with either function easyQuiz or hardQuiz, one which takes you to an easy quiz, one which takes you to a hard. What ever value difficulty it is, it should use that array of answers. The problem I have is that I dont think the array of answers is being loaded because I get an error saying 'answers' is not defined.

```
// Insert number of questions
var numQues = 4;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// To set quiz difficulty
var difficulty = 0;

function easyQuiz (difficulty){
difficulty = 1;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(4);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Apple"] ;
answers[1] = ["Dynamic HTML"];
answers[2] = ["Netscape"];
answers[3] = ["Common Gateway Interface"];
}

function hardQuiz (difficulty) {
difficulty = 2;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
 var answers = new Array(4);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Test"] ;
answers[1] = ["Test"];
answers[2] = ["Test"];
answers[3] = ["Test"];
}





// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
 var currElt;
 var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
  currElt = i*numChoi;
  for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
    currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
    if (currSelection.checked) {
      if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
        score++;
      break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";
var correctAnswers = "";
 for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
  correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
 form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}
//  End -->
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide the HTML portion and any CSS you might have?

Comment: You've declare var answers = new Array() within your functions. This makes the array local to that function. You need to declare the array outside of the functions just like you did with var numQue etx

Comment: Don't worry about posting the HTML and (especially) CSS. They're not relevant to this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the `answer` variables inside the function, which means that they are local to the function and doesn't exist any more once the function ends.

Declare the variable outside the functions to make it global.

Also, you are putting arrays as items in the arrays, judging by the rest of the code you should just put the strings in the arrays.

```
var answers;

function easyQuiz (difficulty){
  difficulty = 1;

  // Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
  answers = new Array(4);

  // Insert answers to questions
  answers[0] = "Apple";
  answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML";
  answers[2] = "Netscape";
  answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface";
}

function hardQuiz (difficulty) {
  difficulty = 2;

  // Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
  answers = new Array(4);

  // Insert answers to questions
  answers[0] = "Test";
  answers[1] = "Test";
  answers[2] = "Test";
  answers[3] = "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the answer variable locally inside your function.

If you want to access the answer array, you must declare it on upper scope.

```
var answers = [];
function easyQuiz (){
    difficulty = 1;
    answers = ["Apple", "Dynamic HTML", "Netscape", "Common Gateway Interface"];
}
```